# app is run in all devices perfectly but in samsung galaxy note 3 and j5 it is crashed at play sound

Tags: android

//playSound method and use it everywhere

```
 public void playSound1() {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), (R.raw.clave_pop));  //sound file clave_pop in mp4 format firstly it is in m4a format then produced same problem then i use mp3 file
                if (sec_sound && mp != null)  //shared preference of sec_sound
                    mp.start();
                if (vibration)//also vibrate if shared preference of vibrator is true
                    v.vibrate(700);   //vibrate device

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
            }

        // and i am also used this but the same problem is occurred

        public void playSound1() {
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Anulom_Activity.this, R.raw.clave_pop);  //sound file clave_pop in mp4 format firstly it is in m4a format then produced same problem then i use mp3 file
            if (sec_sound && mp != null) //shared preference of sec_sound
                mp.start();
            if (vibration) //also vibrate if shared preference of vibrator is true
                v.vibrate(700);  //device vibrate
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }

    // but it shows 

/* java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.pixelpoint.Anulom_Activity.playSound1(Anulom_Activity.java:727)
        at com.pixelpoint.Anulom_Activity$5$1$1.run(Anulom_Activity.java:325)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) */
```

Comment: Is it running a custom rom?

Comment: Is there android 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MediaPlayer create (Context context,Uri uri)
> ```
>
> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given Uri. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be
>   called again.
>       When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will
>   result in an exception.
>       Note that since prepare() is called automatically in this method, you cannot change the audio stream type (see setAudioStreamType(int)),
>   audio session ID (see setAudioSessionId(int)) or audio attributes (see
>   setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes) of the new MediaPlayer.
>       Parameters
>       context   Context: the Context to use
>       uri   Uri: the Uri from which to get the datasource
>       Returns
>       MediaPlayer   a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed
>       deselectTrack

```
prepare ()
```

> Prepares the player for
>   playback, synchronously. After setting the datasource and the display
>   surface, you need to either call prepare() or prepareAsync(). For
>   files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks until MediaPlayer is
>   ready for playback.

as per above documentation you need call prepare or prepare async and set Onpreparelistener. Wait for call back and then call mp.start or set Oncompletion listener.